# Range of $(x+y+z, xy+yz+zx, xyz)$ when $x^2+y^2+z^2\leq 1$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I would like to know the range of the function $(x, y, z) \mapsto (x+y+z, xy+yz+zx, xyz)$ when $x^2+y^2+z^2\leq 1$.

**My attempt:**
Since $x^2+y^2+z^2=(x+y+z)^2-2(xy+yz+zx)$, we have $(x+y+z,xy+yz+zx,xyz)\in \{(u,v,w)|u^2-2v\leq 1\}$.
But we can easily see by polar coordinate, we have a restriction on $xyz$, so we need a better representation.

I probably can use Vieta’s formula as it looks similar, but do not really know how.

Comment: Do you want the image or merely some restriction on the range? For example, we see that $\max{|x|,|y|,|z|}\leq 1$ this shows that the range is a bounded set.

Comment: By the CM-GM inequality you can obtain a bound for the third coordinate: $\sqrt[3]{xyz}\leq \sqrt{(x^2+y^2+z^2)/3}\leq 1/\sqrt{3}$

Comment: @Kapil Oh, an apology for the bad wording; I wanted to know the image.

Comment: For the polynomial $T^3+a T^2+b T+c$ to have all its roots real, the discriminant has to be non-negative. So that would be one boundary condition.